# Alert controller not responding as expected

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have the following .ts file :

```
// all imports are made.

export class Alert {
     alertPresent(){
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Hello',
        message: 'Alert Controller',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'OK',
            role: 'cancel'
        }]
    });
    alert.present();
}}
```

**.ts**

```
import {NgModule, ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';

class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

constructor(public alert:Alert)
  handleError(error) {
    // do something with the exception
    this.alert.alertPresent();
  }
}
```

When I click on the button that issues the alert box using the alert controller, the alert box only appears when I click a second time somewhere else on the screen. It does not display the alert box when clicking the first time on the button.

Why is this happening?

Please ignore typos and syntax errors.

Comment: Can you include the code where your are using this `Alert` class as well as the code for the button click handler ?

Comment: added the code.Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't see the HTML for your button nor the click handler you defined for it. Can you add those as well ?